# Laravel 4 Eloquent Mass Assignment - Modify Input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am a bit stuck with the mass assignment. I have an input field (datepicker) which needs to get modififies (apply the strtotime function) before inserting it to the database.

Is there a way to do that while using the mass assignment?

```
class Customer extends Ardent {
    protected $table = 'customers';
    public $autoPurgeRedundantAttributes = true;
    public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;   
    public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true; 


    protected $fillable = array(

        'email',
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, but please show us what have you done so far so we have a starting point.

Comment: Well, not sure what i should show you. It is a simple Eloquent model, there is not much to show. I updated my question though. Thanks

Comment: Where are you planning to modify that input field? In your controller? So show us your controller and how you are inserting things in your database, are you using create()? Probably, but how can we be sure? The way it is the question is too broad.

Comment: It depends if we want to update a customer or create a new one. We use the `save()` funtion. It would be okay if we can modify the input directly in the model, or in the controller. Both is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to change the Input, you can do:

```
$input = Input::all();

$input['date'] = strtotime($input['date']);

Input::replace($input);
```